# Swift Ios App performance configuration

Tags: ios, performance, swift

First of all, I'm sorry to ask a somewhat vague question but I'm only doing it because I'm clueless to what might be causing the problem.

I've been building an app with Sprite Kit and it has worked great. I've made some additions to code at suddently I see a dramatic decrease in performance. I have rolled back all my code changes but the performance didn't go up. I'm left clueless to what's wrong.

After hidious debugging I've noticed that the performance problem only affects run and test builds. If I do a profiling build, the app behaves as normally = with high performance. So this would suggest that my problem is somewhere in the build configuration but I'm completely new to ios build environment configurations.

[image]

Can anybody suggest what might be the cause of this? Where should I start looking? I have my background in Java 5 and the compiler and other settings are quite strange to me.

Answer (score 2):

The default setup is to have a Debug config and a Release config, where Debug is configured with no optimizations, and Release does include optimizations. Optimizing often makes it hard to use the debugger, which is why unoptimized code is preferred there.

By default, Run, Test, and Analyze use the Debug config, Profile and Archive use the Release config. Your change in behavior could come from lots of differences: you may have had it configured before to build for Run in Release mode. You may have had a subproject built in Release mode that is now in Debug. You may have made a coding change that is very slow unless the optimizer is used. (Since you say you rolled back the code, this last one is unlikely, but check your version control and see if you changed any project settings.)

If you're seeing weird "it wasn't like that before" behavior when you think you've put everything back, make sure you're rebuilding everything. Delete your Derived Data directory. You can determine where it is in Preferences, Locations. "Delete your Derived Data directory" is the Xcode-equivalent of "try rebooting." It's the most common way to fix strange "Xcode isn't working right" problems. In fact, I put my Derived Data in `/tmp/build` so that it gets deleted every time I reboot (and so the path is easier for me to remember).